# $data is null in __invoke() function with custom POST operation

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I created an operation personalized of type POST with the method of written in the documentation of api platform. The system works but the object **$data of the function __ invoke () stays null** (all propeties of this objet are null)

Here is the code of the class Step:

```
namespace App\Entity\Api;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

use App\Controller\Api\Step\Create as StepCreate;

/**
 * Class Step
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "special"={
 *          "method"="POST",
 *          "path"="/step/create",
 *          "controller"=StepCreate::class,
 *          "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false},
 *     }
 * })
 *
 * @package App\Entity\Api\Step
 */
class Step {

    /**
     * @var null|string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var null|string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $tripId;


    ...

}
```

And the code of the controller:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api\Step;

use App\Entity\Api\Step;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class Create {

    /**
     * @param \App\Entity\Api\Step $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(Step $data) {

        dump($data);
        return $data;
    }

}
```

And here is the result of the dump ($data):

```
<pre>
        <abbr title="App\Entity\Api\Step">Step</abbr> {
        <samp>
    -
            <span title="Private property defined in class:&#10;`App\Entity\Api\Step`">title</span>:
            <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    -
            <span title="Private property defined in class:&#10;`App\Entity\Api\Step`">description</span>:
            <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    -
            <span title="Private property defined in class:&#10;`App\Entity\Api\Step`">latitude</span>:
            <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    -
            <span title="Private property defined in class:&#10;`App\Entity\Api\Step`">longitude</span>:
            <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    -
            <span title="Private property defined in class:&#10;`App\Entity\Api\Step`">tripId</span>:
            <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
        </samp>}
    </pre>
```

**Can someone help me with this?**

thank :)

Comment: did you find a solution for his?

Comment: No, and I think it’s impossible to do that:(

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. I you want to get your `Step` object, you need to get rid of the `"defaults"={"_api_receive"=false},`

see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#entity-retrieval